# When do I need to worry about tasks leading to multithreading?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Say I have code like this:

```
...
var task1 = DoWorkAsync(1);
var task2 = DoWorkAsync(2);
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
...

private async Task DoWorkAsync(int n)
{
    // Async HTTP request that we ConfigureAwait(to be determined).

    // Some CPU-bound work that isn't thread-safe.
}
```

So if I'm in a WPF app and I don't `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the HTTP request, am I safe here? The two HTTP requests can be made concurrently, but the tasks have to resume on the UI thread, so the CPU-bound work isn't multi-threaded? But if I do `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the tasks can resume their CPU-bound work in parallel on different thread pool threads so I'm in trouble?

If I'm in ASP.NET it can happen either way because the synchronization context doesn't have anything to do with a thread like WPF?

And what if I'm in a console app?

How do I talk about `DoWorkAsync`? Do I say 'it's not safe to `DoWorkAsync`s concurrently'?

Is there a normal way to redesign it? The important part to do concurrently is the HTTP request, not the CPU-bound work, so do I use a lock or something (never used before)?

Comment: is above code for server side or client?

Comment: In the future, please ask one question per question.

Comment: @LeiYang: the above code is for a class library that could be used in any one of those three contexts (WPF, ASP.NET, console), I guess.

Comment: Amazing how my question was 'too broad' to be answered 'adequately' and yet Stephen completely and succinctly cleared up everything for me, right guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I'm in a WPF app and I don't ConfigureAwait(false) on the HTTP request, am I safe here?

If this is called on the UI thread, then yes, you are correct. The UI context only allows one thread at a time (the UI thread, to be specific), so the CPU-bound portions will run on the UI thread and not interfere with each other. This is a pretty common trick.

> if I do ConfigureAwait(false), the tasks can resume their CPU-bound work in parallel on different thread pool threads so I'm in trouble?

Yes. Because `ConfigureAwait(false)` means "the CPU-bound work doesn't need the context", so it can run on the thread pool and in parallel.

> If I'm in ASP.NET

Classic ASP.NET has a one-thread-at-a-time request context, so it would behave the same; it's safe if there's no `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

ASP.NET Core does *not* have a request context (well, not a `SynchronizationContext`, anyway), so it can be run in parallel on that platform. I call this ["implicit parallelism" in my blog post on the ASP.NET Core SynchronziationContext](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html).

> And what if I'm in a console app?

There's no context, so it can be run in parallel.

> How do I talk about DoWorkAsync?

"This method requires a non-free-threaded `SynchronizationContext`."

> do I use a lock or something

This is the best approach, yes:

```
private readonly object _mutex = new object();
private async Task DoWorkAsync(int n)
{
  await HttpRequestAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  lock (_mutex)
  {
    // Some CPU-bound work that isn't thread-safe.
  }
}
```